Non-Trailing/Leading '/' is getting removed on proxy_pass
I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy to send requests to localhost:3001. localhost:3001 contains a docker container running a fork of the local version of prerender.io. Thus, a full request would look like server/prerender/https://google.com, and a static, rendered version of google.com gets returned.
The issue is that when I proxy_pass the request to localhost:3001, the pre-renderer logs that it failed to pre-render 'https:/google.com' (a / in https:// was removed). I tested localhost:3001 directly without going through NGINX, and it pre-rendered fine. I tried re-approaching this via rewrite rules and removing the trailing / in proxy_pass, but the end product is the same where it logs that it can't pre-render 'https:/google.com'.
Setup:
  location /prerender/ {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/; 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

}

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

I'm not 100% sure, but I was able to fix this issue by having the URL (https://google.com) be entered as a query so /prerender?url=, and I then extracted the arg_url and proxy_passed to localhost:3001/arg_url. I guess the issue was that NGINX was interpreting the URL as part of the actual path, so it interpreted the // in the same it way interprets the / in domain.com/prerender.

You can change this behavior with the merge_slashes directive.

@IvanShatsky Thank you! I had a feeling it was an intended behavior.
